List path to modified files in the latest git commit on GitHub
name: DBexecute - AD

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - 'upload_REMOTEHOST/**/'  # This will detect changes in any subdirectory under upload_REMOTEHOST


jobs:

  setvars:
    runs-on:
      group: "Shared"
    outputs:
      runner_name: ${{ runner.name }} 
      WORKSPACE_LOC: ${{ github.workspace }}
    steps:

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Detect Trigger Type
        run: |
          # Print the event type
          if ($env:GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -eq "workflow_dispatch") {
            Write-Host "Workflow executed by clicking 'Run workflow'"
          } elseif ($env:GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -eq "push") {
            Write-Host "Workflow executed by pushing a file"
            # Change to the GitHub workspace directory
            Set-Location $env:GITHUB_WORKSPACE
            # Get the name of the current branch
            $CURRENT_BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
            Write-Host "CURRENT_BRANCH is $CURRENT_BRANCH"
            Write-Host "Changes to file are #1"
            git show --name-only
            Write-Host "Changes to file are #2"
            git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format: 
            Write-Host "Changes to file are #3"
            git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $(git rev-parse HEAD)
            Write-Host "Changes to file are #4"
            git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r HEAD
            # Fetch the latest changes from the remote repository for the current branch
            #git fetch origin ${CURRENT_BRANCH}:${CURRENT_BRANCH}
    
            # Get the modified files in the current branch compared to the last commit
            #git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD^ HEAD
            
          } else {
            Write-Host "Unknown event type"
          }

Output:
Changes to file are #1
commit 362402a73e3ac173cfb9bbf52b38e1197fef78c6
Author: User TUR, CRES <usercres@mybank.com>
Date:   Thu Nov 14 08:38:55 2024 +0530

    Update 11DB.sql

.github/workflows/dbexecute.yml
upload_REMOTEHOST/TP00075/11DB.sql
upload_REMOTEHOST/CAN_APP/11sql.db
upload_REMOTEHOST/CCC_APP/11db.sql
upload_REMOTEHOST/tp00055/11db.sql
Changes to file are #2
.github/workflows/dbexecute.yml
upload_REMOTEHOST/TP00075/11DB.sql
upload_REMOTEHOST/CAN_APP/11sql.db
upload_REMOTEHOST/CCC_APP/11db.sql
upload_REMOTEHOST/tp00055/11db.sql
Changes to file are #4

As you can see from the output of git show --name-only only a single file was updated in the latest push i.e 11DB.sql in the path upload_REMOTEHOST/TP00075/11DB.sql
Desired output should be just upload_REMOTEHOST/TP00075/11DB.sql
However, I'm not able to find a command that gives me just the list of added or updated files. I do not wish to show removed files.
I'm using GitHub PowerShell workflow.
Can you please suggest?

See https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files and https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files?tab=readme-ov-file#outputs-.

The correct way in the GitHub environment and pure GIT is:
git diff --name-only ${{ github.event.before }} ${{ github.event.after }}

But I would recommend using changed-files - it handles a lot of other cases not just simple commits, but also PR, forks.
